# Add a "Use Fingerprint" checkbox on login page android studio using java

Tags: android-fingerprint-api

I have created an android studio application and i want to update the login page with fingerprint option. But i want the user puts at least one time username and password and then he can use the fingerprint.

User can login with fingerprint even if he doesn't know the password

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.